# POST data to XML service aspx vb

Tags: asp.net, xml, post

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load("http://www.example.com/?paramx=1&paramy=2")
```

is great for GET queries in the querystring.  But say I wanted to POST the paramx=1&paramy=2 to http://www.example.com   and get the response in XML.  How would I do that?

Comment: You will need to use the HttpWebRequest and response I guess. Nice sample here: http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-1-0-1-1-professional/57098-c-post-xml-using-httpwebrequest-response.html

Comment: If you are asking how to post from HTML and get XML response, you can use form method POST to submit or AJAX to post. On the server side you probably use what Yeronimo has said as I'm not into ASP.NET.

Comment: Great @yeromino the keyword I was looking for was "httpwebrequest" there's loads of tutorials out the for vb, your example was for c# but that's cool. thanks.

Comment: @Indoknight yeah.  serverside is what i looking for.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a helper class I use for POSTing data to a website which then returns XML - hope it helps.

Usage:

```
var resultXmlDoc = new HttpHelper().PostXml("http://www.test.com", new { paramName = "value", paramName2="value2" });
```

Helper class:

```
internal class HttpHelper
{

    public XDocument PostXml(string baseUrl, IDictionary<string, string> cgiParams)
    {
        return XDocument.Load(Post(baseUrl, cgiParams).GetResponseStream());
    }

    public XDocument PostXml(string baseUrl, params object[] items)
    {
        return XDocument.Load(Post(baseUrl, items).GetResponseStream());
    }

    public XDocument PostXml(string url, string topost)
    {
        return XDocument.Load(Post(url, topost).GetResponseStream());
    }

        protected virtual HttpWebResponse Post(string url, string postString)
        {
            if (url == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("baseUrl");

            Uri uri;
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
                throw new ArgumentException("url is not a valid Uri");


            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            // if the target site issues a session cookie, you need to store it and append it here
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Method = "POST";
            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postString);
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            using(var str = req.GetRequestStream())
                str.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);


            return (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        }

        protected virtual HttpWebResponse Post(string url, params object[] items)
        {
            var x = items.SelectMany(i =>
            {
                return i.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => new Tuple<string, string>(p.Name, p.GetValue(i, null) != null ? p.GetValue(i, null).ToString() : ""));
            });

            var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var p in x)
                d[p.Item1] = p.Item2;

            return Post(url, d);
        }


        protected virtual HttpWebResponse Post(string baseUrl, IDictionary<string, string> cgiParams)
        {
            if (baseUrl == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("baseUrl");

            Uri uri;
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(baseUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
                throw new ArgumentException("baseUrl is not a valid Uri");


            string postString = string.Empty;
            if (cgiParams != null && cgiParams.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var k in cgiParams.Keys)
                    postString += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(k) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cgiParams[k]) + "&";

                postString = postString.Substring(0, postString.Length - 1);
            }

            return Post(baseUrl, postString);
        }
}
```